# Why Backward-stepwise algorithm can only be used when N>p

Tags: model-selection, model

I am reading the chapter 3.3.2 Forward- and Backward-Stepwise Selection on "The Elements of Statistical Learning".

In this chapter, how to select subset of variables is written.

Roughly, What Forward- and Backward-Stepwise Selection does is clear.
But,I cannot understand that why BackWard-Stepwise algorithm only does not work on N < p.

If the problem is caused by data-sparsity, Forward- algorithm also does not work, right?

- N is the size of data-set.
- p is the dimension of explanatory variable.

Comment: How exactly would you even get started?  With backward selection methods you begin by including all the variables--but that's impossible when $n \lt p$, unless you have some special kind of regression method in mind.  What would it be?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment.  I think if the size of data-set is extreamly low than p, some estimated result will be calculated. But, it performs very poor result. You mean the differences of two algorithms is initial size of predictive variables and forward one starts with less number, it will bring better result than backward one, is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

If we only have one data point then we wouldn't be able to solve for 2 parameters

As all the lines passing through one data point will have zero residuals and thus all the lines minimize RSS. Thus it's not until we have 2 data points that it becomes clear that line passing both data points is one with least RSS.
Thus to solve linear equations with n unknown variables, we will need at least n data points to solve.

This makes forward stepwise selection the only subset method which can be used when $n<p$ as it begins with a model that utilizes no predictors and successively adds predictors one-at-a-time.